# Gmail API request hangs indefinitely when sending a batch of emails

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API to send a batch of emails. In some cases, the API request hangs indefinitely without returning a success or error response. Below is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```js
try {
  logger.info("Attempting to send");
  await client.users.messages.send({
    userId: "me",
    requestBody: {
      raw,
    },
  });
  logger.info("sent");
} catch (error) {
  logger.error("error", error);
}
```

Most of the time, the code works fine and the emails are sent successfully. However, there are occasional instances where the `client.users.messages.send` function hangs indefinitely.

I'm looking for suggestions or insights on why this issue might be occurring and potential solutions to resolve it.